# Javascript sort index linked array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Sorry if this has already been asked but I did search "javascript sort index linked array" and found nothing satisfactory.

I've got an array of names, and another index linked array which records the frequency at which the names appear in a passage, and I want to sort both arrays not alphabetically but according to the name frequencies - say, most frequent to least frequent. I've got the following bit of code which does the job adequately, but I'm thinking that it looks like a hack. Surely there's a more decorous way to solve what must be a pretty common sorting problem.

I start with an array of names[] say, 6 Johns, 2 Annes, 9 Toms, 12 Andrews, 3 Kristens, 1 Archie, and 14 Peters - already sorted alphabetically and counted into frequencies, and the routine below results in an array of indexes to the names and frequency arrays which allows me to display the names and frequencies in order from highest to lowest.

```
var names = ["Andrew", "Anne", "Archie", "John", "Kristen", "Peter", "Tom"];
var frequency = [12, 2, 1, 6, 3, 14, 9];
var holder = [], secondpart = [], numindex = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < frequency.length; i++) {
    if (frequency[i] < 10) {
        holder[i] = "0" + frequency[i] + "!" + i;    // add leading zeros as required
    }
    if (frequency[i] > 9) {
        holder[i] = frequency[i] + "!" + i;    // no leading zeros required
    }
}
holder.sort();
holder.reverse();
for (i = 0; i < holder.length; i++) {
    secondpart[i] = holder[i].substring(holder[i].indexOf("!") + 1, holder[i].length);
    numindex[i] = parseInt(secondpart[i]);
}
```

I can now list both arrays according to the name frequencies.

```
var txt = "";
var useindex;
for (i = 0; i < numindex.length; i++) {
    useindex = numindex[i];
    txt = txt + names[useindex] + " - " + frequency[useindex] + "<br>";
}
```

Has anyone else had this problem and how did you solve it.

Comment: You can pass a callback to `.sort()` to guide how the sort works.

Comment: What is an "*index linked array*"? Sounds like a  [parallel array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array), but I'm not sure.

Comment: You should use objects ("tuples" if you want) instead of serialising your data into strings.

Comment: Little confused by your code. Could you also provide a before array and a desired result?

Comment: The before array would be and array of names[] say, 6 Johns, 2 Annes, 9 Toms, 12 Andrews, 3 Kristens, 1 Archie, and 14 Peters. The result would be an array of indexes to the names and frequency arrays where Peter would be first in the text output with a frequency of 14, and Archie would be last in the text output with a frequency of just 1.

Comment: The names[] array is sorted alphabetically and I want to resort it, or at least have an array of indexes so that I can display the frequencies - highest to lowest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var names = ["Adam", "Peter", "Mahu", "Lala"];
var frequencies = [6,2,9,1];

var tupples=[];
for(let i = 0; i<names.length; i++)
{
    tupples[i] = {
       frequency : frequencies[i],
       name : names[i]
    };
}

//ascending
//tupples.sort(function(a,b){return a.frequency-b.frequency;});

//descending
tupples.sort(function(a,b){return b.frequency-a.frequency;});

for(let i=0; i<tupples.length; i++)
{
    console.debug(tupples[i].name, tupples[i].frequency);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could use the indices and sort them by getting the the frequency for the given index.

```js
var names = ['Andrew', 'Anne', 'Archie', 'John', 'Kristen', 'Peter', 'Tom'],
    frequency = [12, 2, 1, 6, 3, 14, 9],
    indices = names.map(function(_, i) { return i; });

indices.sort(function(a, b) {
    return frequency[b] - frequency[a];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(indices, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write(indices.map(function(a) { return names[a]; }).join('<br>'));
```